# How can I make this jQuery code more efficient?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-events

I'm just starting with jQuery and I'm running into a few things. I've animated my site and added slideDown drop menus. The problem is that the drop menus seem to be intermittent and take forever to load. I'm pretty sure it's because I've got them all broken down into separate scripts, but when I try to put everything between one set of  tags, everything breaks. So I'd like to know how I can possibly make this more efficient. Here's the jQuery I'm using...

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".info").hide();
                $(".menu").hide();
                $(".info").fadeIn(2000,
                function() {$("#servdiv").slideDown(800,
                function() {$("#condiv").fadeIn(800,
                function() {$("#testdiv").fadeIn(800,
                function() {$("#disdiv").fadeIn(800);});
                });
                });
            });
                return false;           
            });
 </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fader").hide();
        $(".phone").hide();
        $(".slider").animate({height: 115}, {duration: 3000, 
        complete: function() { $(".fader").fadeIn({duration:3000,
        complete: function() { $(".phone").fadeIn({duration: 3000,}); }}); }});
        });
        return false;   

 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#servdiv").hover(function() {
                $("#servsub").slideDown('slow')
            }, function() { 
                $("#servsub").slideUp('slow')
            })
        });
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#condiv").hover(function() {
                $("#consub").slideDown('slow')
            }, function() {
                $("#consub").slideUp('slow')
            })
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testdiv").hover(function() {
            $("#testsub").slideDown('slow')
        }, function() {
            $("#testsub").slideUp('slow')
        })
    });
</script>
```

I'm guessing all of the nested functions are slowing things down, but it's the only way I can get sequential animations. Also - It looks great in Chrome but terrible in Firefox. Is there any way I can clean this up, make it load quickly, and look great across all browsers?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you share the page source (at least the menu) ?

Comment: sure. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejaesajdjkn9a6u/index.html - didn't want to copy/paste all the code. I'm very aware that it's a mess so let me pass on that one lol. The step I'm on right now is getting it all cleaned up with a .css and .js - I apologize if it's a little hard to read.

Comment: It may be worth noting that I'm using id's for the animation instead of classes because when I told it to animate the class, all menus opened no matter which link you hover on. I tried to use I tried to use "this" to try to tell it to only animate the submenu associated with that div but I don't think I wrote it correctly...